# GHCi different behavior for value with/without Show constraint

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghci

I was trying to understand what GHCi does to print values, I thought it would just do something like call `putStrLn . show` on the value, but then this happened:

```
a = return 5 :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a
a -- prints 5

b = return 5 :: (Monad m, Num a, Show (m a)) => m a
b -- Ambiguous type variable `m0`...
```

Why is it that adding the show constraint change this behavior? I thought that'd be assumed when trying to print the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `ghci` works in `IO` monad. So when you're trying to evaluate `a` its `m` type variable becomes `IO`. And `a` variable has type `Num a => IO a`. When you evaluate `IO` action inside repl, `ghci` just performs it and prints result. In your case this is `Num a => a` (and default for polymorphic variables with `Num` constraint in `ghci` is `Integer` data type).

But `IO` data type doesn't have `Show` instance. There's no such instance and it can't even exist! Before evaluating some expression in `ghci`, it should satisfy all constraints. Since it can't satisfy `Show (IO a)` (because there's no such instance) it can't substitute `IO` for `m` type variable. But then: which `m` do you exactly want? `ghci` can't guess for you. Behaviour is different for different `m`s.

```
ghci> b = return 5 :: (Monad m, Num a, Show (m a)) => m a
ghci> b :: Maybe Int
Just 5
ghci> b :: [Int]
[5]
```

Comment: To be precise, for example `instance Show (IO a) where show _ = "<IO>"` *can* exist, it just doesn't.

Comment: @luqui you're right, you can write such instance. You can even use `unsafePerformIO` if you feel risky enough... It just won't be useful. Sorry for not being precise enough in my answer.

Comment: If you want this to work, the `Show` constraint needs to be `Show a`, not `Show (m a)`.

Comment: Thanks for your very good answer, Shersh. Just a quick thing before accepting this, could you share some source of how this type defaulting happens? I couldn't find it in GHC's GHCi docs.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD This is a good blog post about type defaulting: https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html